# There is a secret message in the picture #3

Tags: cipher, visual, steganography, mystery

[image]

This picture is from the 50 trillion dollars challenge from the free ebook ["Muko and the Secret"](http://aivirai.com/muko-part-i/). This one is already solved by a reader.

Comment: Wait, is this part of an ongoing challenge?

Comment: The whole challenge is not yet solved, but like I have written below the picture: "This one is already solved by a reader" - it means that the message from this picture is already found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My final answer is

> naturals class

I noticed that there are

> smaller and bigger stones in the archway. Reading them clockwise I get `–••––••–•–••–•–•••••`

Then I tried to decipher that

> as morse code. I found no hint how to split that up in letters, so I tried until I got a meaningful word: `–• •– – ••– •–• •– •–•• •••` = **naturals**

I then noticed there is still more:

> On the floor are also two lines that look like morse code: `–•–••–••` and `•–••••••`.

I finally managed to decipher that.

> It splits up as `–•–• •–•• •– ••• •••` which reads as **class**

Comment: Definitely it - all the other ones have followed this pattern.

Comment: Currently only "morse-based" secret messages were found in a book (that is why all the pictures I have uploaded were following this pattern).
As for the solution - it is only a part of the whole message. Still something is missing.